# For a random permutation a of the values $1,2,3,...,n$ what is the expected value of the sum of the absolute values of $|a_i-i|$ for $i=1,2,...,n$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I assume with the linearity of expectations the expectation of the sum should be the sum of the expectations of $|a_i - i|$. But I just can't work out how to calculate the expectation of $|a_i - i|$. I've tried with $E[a_i] = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ and also $E[a_i] = E[a_{i-1}]- \frac{1}{n}E[a_{i-1}]$. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An obvious first step is to consider this for small $n$.

Comment: Try conditioning on whether $a_i$ is greater than i

Comment: Suppose $n=5$, and consider $i = 3.$  Then, the expectation, for that particular value of $i$ is $$\frac{2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2}{5}.$$  Similarly, for $n=5$ and $i=2$, the expectation is $$\frac{1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3}{5}.$$

Comment: notice that $a_i$ itself is a uniform random variable over $1,2,\dots,n$

Answer (score 2):

Use linearity of expectation to find $$\mathbb{E}(\sum|a_i - i|) = \sum\mathbb{E}(|a_i - i|)$$

How to find $\mathbb{E}(|a_i - i|)$?

Divide the numbers into two groups $1, 2, \cdots, i$ and $i + 1, i + 2, \cdots, n$ and add the differences up. Each number has a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$.

For numbers $k = 1, 2, \cdots, i$, the difference is $i - k$.

For numbers $k = i + 1, i + 2, \cdots, n$, the difference is $k - i$.

So, the sum is $$\frac{1}{n} \bigg(\sum_{k = 1}^{i}(i - k) + \sum_{k = i +1}^{n}(k - i)\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\bigg(i^2 - (1 + 2 + \cdots + i) + ((i + 1) + (i + 2) \cdots + n) - i(n - i) \bigg)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2n} \bigg((i - 1)i + (n - i)(n - i + 1) \bigg)$$

For all $1 \leq i \leq n$, the sum is

$$=\frac{1}{n} \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (i - 1)i \bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n} \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (i^2 - i) \bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{n} \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}i \bigg)$$

If you sum them up for all $1 \leq i \leq n$  using $$\sum i^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$
$$\sum i = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$

We find answer $$\boxed{\frac{(n - 1)(n + 1)}{3} = \frac{n^2 - 1}{3}}$$

Comment: right : I used this in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336940/

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$, then the expected value is 0.

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than 1, $i$ be a positive integer less than $n$ and let $X$ be an integer that is equally likely to be any of the integers from $1$ to $n$. The expected value of $|X-i|$ is
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |j-i|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} |j-i|+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} |j-i|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} |j-i|+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} |j-i|$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} (i-j)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} (j-i)$$
Now, you can do this using arithmetic series formula.
Using Mathematica

```
Simplify[(1/n) Sum[i - j, {j, 1, i}] + (1/n) Sum[j - i, {j, i + 1, n}]]
```

This evaluates to $(2i^2-2 i (1 + n) + n(1 + n))/(2 n)$.
Now, this formula may or may not apply for the term when $i=n$ because we assumed $i<n$, but the sum of all the expected values is

```
Simplify[Sum[(2i^2-2 i (1 + n) + n(1 + n))/(2 n), {i,1,n-1}] + (1/n) Sum[n-j, {j, 1, n}]]
```

which evaluates to $(n^2-1)/3$